# How to get all columns from table by name

Tags: laravel, database

I am new to laraveI have problem, please help.
I have database with id, name, model, price and description how can I get in laravel all the others from the same row if I know only one of them, for example name.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide desired output and what you tried so far?

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent method:

```
Table::where('name', $name)->get();
```

Query builder method:

```
DB::table('table')->where('name', $name)->get();
```